# Python - Calculating Percent of Column Total in Pivot Tables

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

The following code gives me the percentage of

```
df_percentage = np.round(df*100/df.iloc[-1,-1], 1)
df_percentage.tail(5)
```

But this gives me the percent of grand total:
[percentage of grand total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUjEe.png)

I would like to get another pivot table that displays values as a percentage of column total like this:

[percentage of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9b0q.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compute each column percentage by summing row-wise and divide each data based on that corresponding column "sum".

Try this:

```
np.round((df/df.sum(axis=0))*100,1)
```

Comment: Instead of 100, its giving me 50%

Comment: @NicoleArdizzi can you show me the steps that you have taken and the data. It shouldn't give you 50% since all rows in a column is sum, then each row of that column is divided by the column "sum". I am suspecting data or steps that have been taken are where the issues lie.

Answer (score 0):

JK Chai's answer would have been correct if the df did not include the total sum of each row and column (this was calculated using margins=True in the pivot_table function). I was able to resolve using the following code:

```
df_percentage = np.round(df*100/df.iloc[-1], 1)
```